# Does the damage caused by Wall of Fire get the implement bonus when a creature walks into it?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, sustained-powers

Our wizard cast a [Wall Of Fire](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=722) which is an implement power.

- Does the damage that is caused when a creature starts their turn adjacent to or in the wall of fire get to add the implement's enhancement bonus?
- Does the bonus get added when a creature moves into the fire? If different from the question above, why?
- Is the bonus added during the wizards turn if the wall is created in the creature's square?
- Would it be different for any other sustained powers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes to the first two questions.

From the [implement](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=69) description in the glossary.

> If you wield a magic implement, you can add its enhancement bonus to the attack rolls and the damage rolls of implement powers you use through it.

All of the damages you ask about are damage rolls of the Wall of Fire power.  They don't need to specify that you add the implement enhancement bonus as that is inherent in the "implement" keyword.

Compare to the good ole [Fireball](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1553) spell.  Same thing, implement power which does not specifically tell you to add the implement enhancement bonus.

@Iszi pointed out that Wall of Fire does not do any damage on the turn it is created (unless after creation a creature moves into it.)  As for other sustained powers, they'd have to be evaluated individually, however nothing here is specific to Wall of Fire and should suffice for the general case.

Comment: Does this extend to extra attacks with Chaos Bolt as well?  Sorry I don't have a link to it since I don't have a DDI subscription.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers, in that the bonuses of your magic implement should apply to damage dealt by the wall.

However, there is are other points that should be addressed with your third and fourth questions.

> Is the bonus added during the wizards turn if the wall is created in the creature's square?

According to the description of the power, damage is triggered by a creature starting its turn adjacent to or within the wall's area.  Therefore, no damage is dealt by the wall on the wizard's turn - it happens at the start of the target creature's turn.  (This brings up another question which I may post separately.)

> Would it be different for any other sustained powers?

This is a question that I would consider generally unanswerable.  Every rule call should be judged on a case-by-case basis, as the specifications and wording of power effects vary greatly.

Comment: Good points!  Do you mind if I edit my answer to account for them?  (with attribution, of course)

Comment: @Pat:  I suppose it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I agree that a power can override what happens, I was just asking for the general case where there aren't any special rules in a power.